# Early 2015 Macbook Air (A1466) Not Charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

I have searched far and wide to try and solve this issue but have had 0 luck.

I have an early 2015 MacBook Air (A1466) that I've kept in great condition over the years. It's never really left my room/desk and I've gone far out of my way to keep it in this condition because of how much I like this computer.

So, it had been a few months since I last used it (new job, work computer, travel all the time) and I realized the charger had been disconnected at some point meaning the battery had been likely sitting there completely dead for days, weeks, possibly months which I understand is not great for a Lithium-Ion battery?

I just tried to power it on for the first time the other day and it boots up, while plugged in, and loads seemingly normal but when the computer is finally completely started up the battery is indicated as "not charging" when clicking on the icon from the taskbar and the percentage is stuck at 1%.

The orange light on the MagSafe charger is on when plugged in.

The steps I've taken so far.

- Reset SMC a few times
- Reset PRAM a few times
- Option + clicked on the battery to see a report and it shows as
  "normal"
- Downloaded coconut battery and that also shows as "normal"
- Checked the cycle count which is currently sitting at about ~310
  which seems well under the expected failure point
- Removed my battery and checked the inside of my computer for
  corrosion or any other type of damage found nothing
- Inspected the battery for any oddities or swelling, found nothing.
- Tried multiple MagSafe chargers  Charged another Macbook using my
  MagSafe charger

A friend of mine had me take some photos of the IO board to see if he could figure it out and isn't sure but seems to think there might be something up with that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/to6fm.jpg - IO board pictures.